# Angular apply function to child array

Tags: angularjs

I have this model:

```
.factory('Api', ['$resource', 'apiUrl', function ($resource, api) {
    var Api = $resource(api + ':path', {
        path: '@path'
    });

    return Api;
}])

.factory('Order', ['$filter', 'Api', function ($filter, api) {
    var Order = api;

    angular.extend(Order.prototype, {
        getDescription: function () {
            var rolls = 0,
                cuts = 0,
                skus = [],
                lines = $filter('orderBy')(this.lines, 'sku');

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var line = lines[i];

                switch (line.type) {
                    case 0: // cut
                        cuts++;
                        break;
                    case 1: // roll
                        rolls++
                        break;
                }

                if (skus.indexOf(line.sku) == -1) {
                    skus.push(line.sku);
                }
            }

            var description = '';
            description += cuts > 0 ? cuts > 1 ? cuts + ' x cuts' : cuts + ' x cut' : '';
            description += rolls > 0 && description.length > 0 ? ', ' : '';
            description += rolls > 0 ? rolls > 1 ? rolls + ' x rolls' : rolls + ' x roll' : '';
            description += skus.length == 1 ? ' of ' + skus[0] : '';
            return description;
        }
    });

    return Order;
}]);
```

As you can see, there are **lines** in the order, I would like to attach a function (**getStatus**) to each **line** so that I can call it from my **view**, like this:

```
<div class="tile large" tile ng-repeat="line in viewOrder.order.data.lines" id="{{ viewOrder.order.data.orderNumber }}{{ line.id }}">
    <div class="text">
        <strong>{{ line.getStatus() }}</strong>&nbsp;<span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

does anyone know how I would do that?

**Update 1**

This is how I use **getDescription()** for an order.

```
<a class="tile large" ng-href="/customer-services/view-order/{{ order.orderNumber }}" tile ng-repeat="order in customerServices.recent.data" id="{{ order.orderNumber }}">
    <div class="text">
        <strong ng-bind="order.account.accountNumber"></strong> <span ng-bind="order.account.name"></span><br />
        <span ng-bind="order.raisedBy"></span><br />
        <span ng-bind="order.orderNumber"></span><br />
        <span ng-bind="order.getDescription()"></span><br />
    </div>
</a>
```

As you can see the **Order** model can return an array of orders. In the view I call the function **getDescription()** for each order. I assume because I am calling it in a **ng-repeat** the object that **this** is bound to is the actual **Order**.
I need to do the same thing for the **lines**.

Comment: you are talking about having the factory to set the data... having the controller call this factory and then save it to the scope then from the scope modifying the view? or do you want it updated directly from the factory?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying here. But I have updated my question to show how I use getDescription.

Comment: sorry m8, Im just not getting what your trying to do. if you have a solution that works go with it... if you want to call the function and post the data in the html why not just preprocess it in the controller if you want it on click why not use ng-click.... Im just not getting what you're trying to accomplish here.... sorry

Comment: Hi :) I am trying to format some data for each "line" in an order. In this case it is status, if the status matches a certain thing then they display a line of text and possible a link. I don't want to have to loop through  the results after I have done the call. On the other screen where I have a list of orders, I add a function that can be called which does a similar thing for the order. The problem with the lines is that they are an array inside of an order, so I am not sure how to do the same thing for them. I hope that makes sense!